# Designing a UI framework for multiple platforms

Tags: c++, qt, design-patterns, inheritance

We're working on an embedded software UI framework based on Qt which would currently power 2 types of devices -  a phone and a tablet. Later on there might be other form factors which will have completely different UIs. The UI currently is similar for both the phone and the tablet with differences mostly being in dimensions. We would like to expose a common API to application developers (internal, no external apps) so that they don’t have to write separate screens for each platform.

To develop a screen, the app developer has to inherit from a Screen class, or from a more specialized screen such as PrefScreen class. We wanted to expose a uniform interface for each component to app developers, but with platform specific implementations in the framework. We have the following classes:

ScreenBase (Exposes interfaces common to all platforms)
ScreenPhone : ScreenBase
ScreenTablet : ScreenBase

PrefScreenBase (Exposes interfaces common to all platforms) 
PrefScreenPhone: PrefScreenBase
PrefScreenTablet: PrefScreenBase

To achieve it we have the following type defs:

```
#ifdef PHONE
typedef ScreenPhone Screen;
typedef PrefScreenPhone PrefScreen;
#elif TABLET
typedef ScreenTablet Screen;
typedef PrefScreenTablet PrefScreen;
#endif
```

The inheritance structure is as follows
ScreenBase 
|_ScreenPhone 
|_ScreenTablet

PrefScreenBase : Screen (resolves to ScreenPhone or ScreenTablet based on the platform it’s built for) 
|_PrefScreenPhone 
|_PrefScreenTablet

Screen would resolve to ScreenPhone on the build for the phone, and resolve to ScreenTablet on the build for the tablet.
PrefScreen would resolve to PrefScreenPhone on the build for the phone, and resolve to PrefScreenTablet on the build for the tablet.

On the phone, the hierarchy would be ScreenBase->ScreenPhone->PrefScreenBase->PrefScreenPhone
On the tablet, the hierarchy would be ScreenBase->ScreenTablet->PrefScreenBase->PrefScreenTablet

In essence, the platform specific classes derive from the common *Base classes, and the *Base classes derive from the appropriate class based on the platform it is built for.
We considered using the Bridge Pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) to solve the problem but our deadlines don’t seem to allow that. Also since our framework is based on the Qt framework,  separating the implementation from the interfaces would be complicated.

Is the above mentioned approach being used in any frameworks? Do you see major problems with the mentioned approach? If so, what would be the alternative?
Our main goals are to abstract away the platform differences to application developers, and to ensure maximum code reuse.

Comment: I recommend you plan this out...

Comment: Have you asked Digia or QtProject for help? Lots of expert advice available from either direction.

Comment: @TonyWittry This is purely a design decision. I'm not sure Digia will be able to help better than anyone else.

Comment: @hyde What happens if PrefScreen needs to be extended further? This Screen hierarchy is just one of the many widget hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use QDesktopWidget:

http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qdesktopwidget.html

as nokia docs say:

> The QDesktopWidget class provides access to screen information on multi-head systems.
>
> Systems with more than one graphics card and monitor can manage the physical screen space  available either as multiple desktops, or as a large virtual desktop.
>
> This class provides information about the user's desktop, such as its total size, number >of screens, the geometry of each screen, and whether they are configured as separate >desktops or a single virtual desktop.
>
> Widgets provided by Qt use this class to place tooltips, menus and dialog boxes on the >correct screen for their parent or application widgets. Applications can use this class to >obtain information that can be used to save window positions, or to place child widgets >and dialogs on one particular screen.

In particular with: QDesktopWidget::screenGeometry() you can get screen resolution in pixel.

Comment: The Screen structure is just an example. There are a lot more widgets for which I need to use a similar design. Getting screen dimensions is not a problem.